Make sequential groups of rows that surpass a minimum sum
Let's say I have a table with a timestamp (ts) and a value (a).
With some sample data:
ts, a
1, 10
2, 30
3, 10
4, 20
5, 40
6, 10
7, 20
8, 30
etc

I would like to group rows, in ts order, by summing a and outputting a row where the sum of a is > 50.
In this case, the output should be two timestamps (first and last row):
1, 3  -- 10 + 30 + 10
4, 5  -- 20 + 40
6, 8  -- 10 + 20 + 30

But I have no clue how to proceed. All attempts I did with Copilot yield complex code that never finishes.

and could you show us the best try you got so far?

Every next row depends on all earlier rows. This lends itself to a procedural solution.
Create this  PL/pgSQL function once:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_chunks(_chunk int)
  RETURNS TABLE (ts1 int, ts2 int, total int)  -- adapt to actual types!
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _r record;
BEGIN
   total := 0;  -- init

   FOR _r IN
      SELECT ts, a
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY ts
   LOOP
      IF total = 0 THEN
         ts1 := _r.ts;  -- add first ts
      END IF;

      total := total + _r.a;

      IF total >= _chunk THEN
         ts2 := _r.ts;  -- add last ts
         RETURN NEXT;
         total := 0;    -- reset total
      END IF;
   END LOOP; 

   -- return remainder, if any?
   IF total > 0 THEN
      ts2 = _r.ts;
      RETURN NEXT;
   END IF;
END
$func$;

Call:
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_chunks(50);

fiddle
I added the total per group, which is easy to suppress.
Or use a temporary function if you don't want to (or can't) persist one. See:

How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?

You can bend the set-based nature of SQL with a recursive CTE. But that's unwieldy and slow in comparison. See:

Postgres: limit by the results of a sum function

